# setup httponly jsessionid cookie on lucee 5

Tags: cookies, jsessionid, httponly, lucee

How do we configure Lucee to ensure that cookie.JSESSIONID are generated as "HTTPOnly"? Or this is job of hosting/vps companies (we do not need to dive into it)?

I have this for CFID, it works perfectly:

> cookie.cfid={path:"/", value:session.cfid, httponly:true};

But not this :

> cookie.jsessionid={path:"/", value:session.sessionid, httponly:true};

Lucee sets it automatically for me without options :(

> Accessible to script: Yes (HTTPOnly=false)

Comment: The jsessionid cookie in my apps is always automatically httpOnly and also secure if under https. What settings do you have for session management in your application.cfc or admin?

Comment: this.sessionManagement = true;
this.sessionType = "cfml";
this.sessioncookie.httponly = true;
this.sessioncookie.secure = true;
this.sessionTimeout = createTimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0);

Comment: i'm on CommandBox that has a Lucee 5.0.1X by the way :P  it's not a production machine :)

Comment: The `jsessionid` cookie is for "j2ee" session management not "cfml". If you want to use "j2ee" sessions then you should just need: `this.sessionType = "J2EE"; this.setClientCookies = false;` It should then set the `jsessionid` cookie with the attributes you want automatically.